# Receive data in browser from service inside Kubernetes Pod

Tags: python, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-service

I have created a pod in Kubernetes(Google Cloud) and its streaming data via imagezmq.

Python code which is streaming the data(Inside Kubernetes Pod)-

```
import imagezmq

sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to='tcp://127.0.0.1:5555', REQ_REP=False)
sender.send_image('rpi_name',data)
```

I want to access the data from outside the pod, from my system like this.

```
image_hub = imagezmq.ImageHub('tcp://34.86.110.52:80', REQ_REP=False)
while True:
    rpi_name, image = image_hub.recv_image()
    yield (b'--frame\r\n'
           b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + image.tobytes() + b'\r\n')
```

I tried creating a external loadbalance but it did'nt worked. I am not sure what to do

Loadbalance YAML-

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.72.131.76
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31145
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 5555
  selector:
    app: camera-65
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: 34.86.110.52
```

Please Help me.

Comment: Whats the error? Paste the output of: kubectl get ep -o wide

Comment: I have edited the question and the output you asked      NAME                           ENDPOINTS         AGE
camera-65-deployment-service   10.72.0.70:5555   165m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Changing the ip from 127.0.0.1 to 0.0.0. solved the issue for me.

```
import imagezmq

sender = imagezmq.ImageSender(connect_to='tcp://0.0.0.0:5555', REQ_REP=False)
sender.send_image('rpi_name',data)
```

Then exposing the pod with LoadBalancer type did the work.